# how to key-bind ESC

Tags: java, eclipse, key-bindings

My problem is that ESC does not do anything, even though it is the same code as for w, a and s which work, and when I push the button, w, a and s no longer work. What this code should do is display the JFrame with a JLabel that should move up, down, left and right when I press w, s, a and ESC respectively. this is the video I was using as a guide (I am not implying it is a bad video) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyfB0u9g2x0&t=118s

```
Game(){
    
        frame = new JFrame("KeyBinding Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420,420);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBackground(Color.red);
        label.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        b = new JButton();
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
        b.setBounds(400, 400, 400, 400);
        b.setOpaque(true);
        upAction = new UpAction();
        downAction = new DownAction();
        leftAction = new LeftAction();
        rightAction = new RightAction();
        
        label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w'), "upAction");
        label.getActionMap().put("upAction", upAction);
        label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s'), "downAction");
        label.getActionMap().put("downAction", downAction);
        label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('a'), "leftAction");
        label.getActionMap().put("leftAction", leftAction);
        label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESC"), "rightAction");
        label.getActionMap().put("rightAction", rightAction);
        frame.add(b);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public class UpAction extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setLocation(label.getX(), label.getY()-10);
        }       
    }
    public class DownAction extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setLocation(label.getX(), label.getY()+10);   
        }       
    }
    public class LeftAction extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setLocation(label.getX()-10, label.getY());   
        }       
    }
    public class RightAction extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setLocation(label.getX()+10, label.getY());
        }       
    }
}
```

This is where I run it

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args ){
        Game game = new Game();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESC"), "rightAction");
```

The label on your keyboard means nothing to Java.

What is important are the variables defined in the KeyEvent class:

```
VK_ESCAPE
```

Therefore to create the KeyStroke you use:

```
label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE"), "rightAction");
```

> but still when i click on the button, the keys stop working

You are using the default InputMap, which will only work when the component has focus. There are 3 InputMaps. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

You should use the `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_COMPONENT` input map. And the key bindings should be added to the content pane of the frame, not the label.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted had more than 50 errors, please provide a complete and compileable example. After fixing the errors, I arrived at the following code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

class Game
{

final JLabel label;

    
Game()
{       
        var frame = new JFrame("KeyBinding Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(420,420);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBackground(Color.red);
        label.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        
        var b = new JButton();
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
        b.setBounds(400, 400, 400, 400);
        b.setOpaque(true);
        var upAction = new UpAction();
        var downAction = new DownAction();
        var leftAction = new LeftAction();
        var rightAction = new RightAction();
        
        label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w'), "upAction");
        label.getActionMap().put("upAction", upAction);
        label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s'), "downAction");
        label.getActionMap().put("downAction", downAction);
        label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('a'), "leftAction");
        label.getActionMap().put("leftAction", leftAction);
        label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESC"), "rightAction");
        label.getActionMap().put("rightAction", rightAction);
        frame.add(b);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public class UpAction extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setLocation(label.getX(), label.getY()-10);
        }       
    }
    public class DownAction extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setLocation(label.getX(), label.getY()+10);   
        }       
    }
    public class LeftAction extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setLocation(label.getX()-10, label.getY());   
        }       
    }
    public class RightAction extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setLocation(label.getX()+10, label.getY());
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args ){
        Game game = new Game();
    }
}
```

Then, the problem with "ESC" is that it seems to not recognize that string, however it works when you supply the key code of escape, for example like this:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
[...]
label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke((char) KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE), "rightAction");
```

Comment: thats 100% my fault, i run the game in another class, then it works

Comment: well you did fix the esc problem, but still when i click on the button, the keys stop working

Comment: I don't experience this problem, if I click on the button it still works. Did you run my code exactly as given with the change below applied?

Comment: yes, everything is the same and i applied the esc change, the imports are also the same